# How can I attach I2C sensors on the small board of Intel Edison?

Tags: arduino-galileo, edison

Sensors like Skin conductance, Body temperature and Heart Rate. Please imagine to talk to a child and keep the answer very simple so I can understand you and you don't lose time to write explanations for your answer.

Comment: Something like https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13034 would be helpful, in connecting. You need at least something to convert the 70-pin Hirose Header into a more usable connection type.

Comment: I didn't get "You need at least something to convert the 70-pin Hirose Header into a more usable connection type."

Comment: The only way to connect anything to the edison is via the 70 pin connector. Unless you're very skilled in soldering, connecting something to these pins with 0.4mm (15mil) spacing is impossible.

Comment: Surely I'm not skilled. It is the only solution you see?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the mini-breakout board (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13025), then you can get the I2C connections from the board (connections available through holes under the Edison; you can see them from the backside; see: https://cdn.sparkfun.com//assets/parts/1/0/0/1/1/13025-02.jpg). You can solder headers on or can solder wires directly to the required pins. You can find the pin mapping here: http://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/mraa/edison.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the [I2C breakout board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13034). This will also handle voltage shift from 1.8 V to the sensor voltage level.